# SQLite Exception no such column "codigo"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to run my code but every time it throws me this exception

> no such column: codigo

This is my code, and the place where it happens.

PolideportivoDAO.java

```
if (init){
                //CategoriaSocial categoria = null;
                List<CategoriaSocial> listaDeCategorias = new Vector<CategoriaSocial>();
                //Categoria Social
                if (CategoriaDAO.getInstance(context).obtenerTodosLasCategorias().size() == 0){
                    listaDeCategorias.add(CategoriaDAO.getInstance(context).crearCategoriaNueva("1", "Miembro A",
                            "Miembro con todos los privilegios, pase diario y uso de la piscina"));
                    listaDeCategorias.add(CategoriaDAO.getInstance(context).crearCategoriaNueva("2", "Miembro B", 
                            "Permiso para uso de las instalaciones tres veces a la semana"));
                    listaDeCategorias.add(CategoriaDAO.getInstance(context).crearCategoriaNueva("3", "Miembro C",
                            "Permiso para uso de las instalaciones solo fin de semana de 8 am a 16 pm"));
                }
```

CategoriaDAO.java

```
public List<CategoriaSocial> obtenerTodosLasCategorias() {
        
        List<CategoriaSocial> categorias = new Vector<CategoriaSocial>();
        
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL, 
                ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.columnasCategoria, null, null, null, null, null);
        
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            CategoriaSocial categoria = crearCategoriaDesdeCursor(cursor);
            categorias.add(categoria);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return categorias;
    }
```

ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.java

```
package com.example.polideportivo1;

public class ICategoriaSQLiteHelper{

    
    public static final String TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL = "Categoria";
    
    public static final String COLUMNA_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMNA_CODIGO = "codigo";
    public static final String COLUMNA_CATEGORIA = "nombre";
    public static final String COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
    
    public static final String[] columnasCategoria = 
        { ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.COLUMNA_ID,
            ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.COLUMNA_CODIGO,
            ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.COLUMNA_CATEGORIA,
            ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION,
            };
    
    public static String TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL_CREACION = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL + "(" + COLUMNA_ID + " INTEGER primary key autoincrement, " 
            + COLUMNA_CODIGO + " TEXT not null unique,"
            + COLUMNA_CATEGORIA + " TEXT not null,"
            + COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION + " TEXT"
            
                    + ");";
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code samples you posted are not sufficient to see where the exception occurs, so I suppose it happens here:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL ...
```

and that 1) the table exists 2) it doesn't contain a column named `"codigo"` (the value of `ICategoriaSQLiteHelper.COLUMNA_CODIGO`).

Aren't you trying to run your code an old table `Categoria` that was created a while ago, and that was not containing a column `codigo`at that time?

If this is so, removing that old table, and creating a new one - this time using `TABLA_CATEGORIA_SOCIAL_CREACION` as in your above samples - should solve the issue.

Comment: i checked with sql admin and was that, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it quite clearly.

You are attempting to access a field in your database that is not there.